# on signup buttonclick of loginpopup I want to show signup popup and also want to disable login popup but my code is not working as it should have to

Tags: asp.net, authentication, popup

```
<div class="body1">
<div class="main">
<!-- header -->
<header>
<h1><a href="index.html" id="logo"></a></h1>
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="icons">
<li><a href="#" class="normaltip"><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="images/lgn.png" ID="btnimg" CssClass="image" /></a></li>
     
</ul>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="btnimg" PopupControlID="Panel1" CancelControlID="Button3"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender >

<asp:panel id="Panel1" CssClass="popup" runat="server">
<div class="popup">
<div id="PopupHeader" style="height:55px;background-color:#f6f6f6;border-radius:10px;width:348px;font-size:2.7em; "> <font style="margin:30px 0px 0px 20px;vertical-align:middle;color:#87a310;line-height:1.2em; font-size:37px; font-family:Calibri;"> Login            </div>
<div class="PopupBody">
<table width="350px" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Name: "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Height="20px" style="border-radius:8px;" 
ValidationGroup="btn"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtUserName_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtUserName" 
WatermarkText="User Name">
</asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password: " ></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Height="20px" style="border-radius:8px;" 
ValidationGroup="btn"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtPassword_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtPassword" 
WatermarkText="Password">
</asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Invalid User Name Or Password." 
Visible="False"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 43.5px">
&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 131.25px">
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Login" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</td>
<td style="width: 131.25px">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Cancle" onclick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="btn" />
</td>
<td style="width: 43.5px">
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 43.5px">
&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 131.25px">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Forgot Password</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
<td style="width: 131.25px">
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Sign Up" onclick="Button3_Click" />
</td>
<td style="width: 43.5px">
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="Button3" PopupControlID="Panel2"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender >

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="popup">

<div class="popupsignup">
<div id="Div1" style="height:55px;background-color:#f6f6f6;border-radius:10px;width:398px;font-size:2.7em; "> <font style="margin:30px 0px 0px 20px;vertical-align:middle;color:#87a310;line-height:1.2em; font-size:37px; font-family:Calibri;"> SignUp Here </font></div>
<div class="PopupBody">
               
</div>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

As shown above I'm having two popups but on imagebuton first popup is getting visible which is alright while clicking on signup button my second popup should be visible which is also alright but in background login popup should must be getting hide while signup pop up is visible.
anyone please help me out from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Solution...
I have to put cacelControlId of popup one to Linkbutton1 Not btnSignup..

Thank Godd..